# Чи штучний прислівник "виключно"?

Tags: вживання-слів

На сайті Культура мови є така стаття стосовно пари слів винятково-виключно:

> Замість того, щоб використовувати синонімічні прислівники на позначення високої міри ознаки — винятково, дуже, надзвичайно, зловживають ***штучно створеним*** словом *виключно*, пор. правильні словосполучення: винятково (дуже, надзвичайно) уважний учень, винятково (дуже, надзвичайно) щастить і неправильні: виключно уважний учень, виключно щастить.
>   У ролі частки бажано замість слова виключно вживати звичні слова тільки, лише, пор.: Уміти говорити і то не лише словами; Допомогу надаватимуть тільки тим, хто перебуває за межею бідності.

Водночас у словнику А.Кримського *виключно* наводиться як відповідник россійському *исключительно* и *наредкость*:

> **Исключи́тельно**, нрч. – ви́ключно, виїмко́во, ви(й)нятко́во, (только) єди́но, одино́ко, (только лишь) са́мо, само́-но, (только кто, что) сам (сама́) за се́бе, сами́ за се́бе, сам-но (сама́-но). [*Ті ви́ключно-тяжкі́ обста́вини, серед яки́х довело́ся животі́ти в Росі́ї украї́нському письме́нству (Єфр.). Мене́ суди́ти могли́-б єди́но ті́льки королі́ (Грінч.). До́брі я́блука покупи́ли, і там лиши́лась сама́ за се́бе па́далиця (Липовеч.). З 1894-го року Коцюби́нський віддає́ себе́ вже самі́й-но розповідні́й, повісте́вій літерату́рі (Єфр.)*].
>
> **Наре́дкость**, нрч. – як рі́дко до, як рі́дко коли́, як неча́сто; (на диво) нади́во, надивови́жу, напро́чуд, (исключительно) *ви́ключно*, виїмко́во; ви(й)нятко́во.

Слово *виключно* вживають у своїх творах О.Вишня, О.Забужко, є воно й у Правописному словнику 1929р. (Г. Голоскевич). То на якій підставі варто відмовитись від його вживання?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**["Як ми говоримо"](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/pryslivnyky) Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича**

> ***Виключно, винятково, тільки, суто, єдино***
>
> *«Він їв виключно черствий хліб»*, — читаємо в медичній статті, хоч важко почути щось подібне в живому народному мовленні й класичній
>   літературі, де було б: *«Він їв самий черствий хліб»* (*«Він їв тільки
>   черствий хліб»*), або, щоб підкреслити сказане: *«Він їв самий тільки
>   черствий хліб»*. ***Прислівник виключно — штучно створене чи
>   скальковане слово, яким надуживають наші науковці й публіцисти, хоч є
>   ще й інші, більш підхожі, природні слова.*** Крім наведеного вище
>   тільки, є ще ***винятково*** («З усіма він чемний і винятково
>   ввічливий». — Я. Баш), ***суто*** («Піднести їй на болячку ту суто
>   золоту гіллячку». — І. Котляревський), ***єдино*** («Мене судити могли
>   б єдино тільки королі». — Б. Грінченко).

**Довідник з українського слововживання М.Волощак ["Неправильно-правильно"](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/chyslivnyky-i-zaimennyky)**

> Виключно одне порівняння ― Єдине порівняння